# Failed to resolve: coordinatorlayout-1.0.0 in android studio

Tags: java, android

when I want create fragment in android studio get error
Failed to resolve: coordinatorlayout-1.0.0

[image]

Comment: Please post your build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed!
just add below line in gradel

```
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.1.0'
```

You may also run into this problem when adding a material library